# Using RakNet source with Code::Blocks on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks, raknet

Hey Forum,
So i'm trying to find out how to use the source files from RakNet with Code::Blocks, in Ubuntu. All the tutorials on the internet are for windows, or use windows ".lib files". I need to find a way to get this working  but I'm getting very discouraged since this is my third day in a row that has been without result.
If anyone can help me at all I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in Advance,
Dan Chevalier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U should install src, headers & libs
download it here http://www.raknet.net/raknet/downloads/
try in console:

```
unzip RakNet-3.*.zip
cd RakNet-3.*
./bootstrap
./configure
make && sudo make install
```

Comment: unzip RakNet-3.*.zip
cd RakNet-3.*
./bootstrap
./configure
make && sudo make install // This Line here, what is it doing? intalling make?

Comment: u should install library and etc from sources. Howto read there http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/softinstall.html

Comment: if u have already installed it, library (in linux libs have *.so extention ) path u can find in console: locate raknet | grep /lib/

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your help with this!!!! I look forward to getting this up and running during class tomorrow !!!